# Install HHVM on Debian 9

Tags: php, linux, debian, hhvm

until now I did the following to install HHVM on Debian 7 and 8

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0x5a16e7281be7a449
echo deb http://dl.hhvm.com/debian jessie main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hhvm.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hhvm
```

Just as it is describer here: https://docs.hhvm.com/hhvm/installation/linux#debian-8-jessie

But this does not work anymore.

I found this: http://ilanco.github.io/blog/2015/09/07/libvpx1-hhvm-debian-stretch/ where I am asked to compile stuff and fiddle around with the source code. I am not really sure to do it that way because it might interfere with future packages of HHVM.

Also one of the developers talks about releasing it end of 2017: https://github.com/hhvm/packaging/issues/128. and gives hints on some nightly build I presume.

Does anyone know what to do? My knowledge of Linux/Debian is too limited.

Help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As for now HHVM isn't supported in debian 9 yet
But the beta can be found here:https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=hhvm

Comment: Thanks for your support. But I'd rather wait until an official package goes online. I don't like betas.

Answer (score 0):

Probably way too late for that answer, but... do you get following error?

```
apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xB4112585D386EB94
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.a1ZUDAMsAq/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0xB4112585D386EB94
gpg: failed to start the dirmngr '/usr/bin/dirmngr': No such file or directory
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/run/user/0/gnupg/d.kny5ngfeab4ewjr7e8b4izxm/S.dirmngr' failed: No such file or directory
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
```

If yes, you just have to `apt-get -y install dirmngr` first.